How to find multiple string formats using MatchCollection
I tried using MatchCollection to figure out the hierarchy using the format of the first letter of the data coming in.
The hierarchy order is like this.

-> 1-1. -> A. -> 1). -> A). -> (1). -> (A).

For example

Input data




Name
price




1. A
1000


1-1. B
600


A. C
500


1). D
400


A). E
300


(1). F
200


(B). G
100



The hierarchy order output from this item looks like.
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
So, I created a regular expression group through MatchCollection and a regular expression site(regex 101), and wrote code to find out which group it matched and print the corresponding index number.


         private void findHierarchy(DataTable dt)
    {

        string _pattern = @"^|(\d\.\s)|(\d+\-\d+\.)|(\D\.)|(\d\)\.)|(\D\)\.)|(\(\d\)\.)|(\(\D\)\.)\s";
        for (int _rowNum = 0; _rowNum < _rowCount; _rowNum++)
        {
            string _matchingValue = dt.Rows[_rowNum]["Name"].ToString();

            MatchCollection _matches = Regex.Matches(_matchingValue, _pattern);
            foreach (Match _match in _matches)
            {
                for (int _depthNum = 0; _depthNum < _match.Groups.Count; _depthNum++)
                {
                    Group _group = _match.Groups[_depthNum];
                    if (_group.Success && _depthNum > 0)
                    {
                        DataRow dr_idx = dt_idx.NewRow();

                        Console.WriteLine($"Group {_group}: {_group.Value}");    
                    }
                }
            }
        }//row

So my question is.

Why the ((\D).) format in a regular expression group does not work properly when grouped?
Is there a better way to understand the hierarchy?


What is the point of the ^| in your regex? That is what is making it not work as expected https://regex101.com/r/aMlg0T/1

When I took that out, the (\d.\s) entry didn't work properly. https://regex101.com/r/RRg5C4/1 Looking at the differences, it appears that " is causing some problem.

You need to use .NET mode on regex101, not PCRE. https://regex101.com/r/Gda3Ef/1

This is my first time using regular expressions so I didn't know there was such a difference. thank you for telling me :D.

No problem. Hopefully then just removing the ^| should resolve your issue.

If you can guarantee, that all strings are in format Prefix. PayLoad where Prefix can be 1., 1-1. etc. you can match up to the first .: ^[^.]+\.
